# Android: Populating a listview with array items

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I'm new to Android and I think I'm trying to do something really basic:  I have a 5 strings in my Array (say 'One', 'Two', ...).  I want to add these 5 strings to my list view in my listactivity.

My List:

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My List Row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView android:id="@+id/homeItemName" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Basically, I want to bind the Array items to the TextView homeItemName.  I might add other items in my row later, so I can't just bind the listview to the entries.

Thanks!

Comment: You need a basic knowledge of Adapters and ArrayAdapters.
You will probably have to extend one of these classes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For code, take a quick look at this [step-by-step tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));  
ListView lv = getListView();
```

It shows a basic implementation of an ArrayAdapter:

R.layout.list_item : is the xml layout (list_item.xml) that will be used for every ROW of your
listview.
COUNTRIES is the array of Strings.

Comment: Link is dead :(. [Is it](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) the one you pointed?

Answer (score 6):

You can use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) to bind your data. Since you want to be able to add extra data items to the view, you to give the adapter an [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) (since an array is of a fixed size). Items should be added via the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and your [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) will be updated automatically. I have an example at http://www.box.net/shared/yduel9txya